# Getting familiar with the definition of $\psi_2$ random variable through an example

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions, random-variables

**Problem:** Let $\xi$ be a real random variable. We say that $\xi$ is $\psi_2$ when $\exists \lambda >0$ such that $\mathbb{E}\exp(\xi^2/\lambda^2) \le e$.

We denote by $\Vert \xi \Vert_{\psi_2}$ the infimum of such $\lambda$, that is

\begin{align*}
    \Vert \xi \Vert_{\psi_2} = \inf\left\{\lambda > 0: \mathbb{E}\exp(\xi^2/\lambda^2) \le e\right\}.
\end{align*}

Prove that if $g \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ then $g$ is $\psi_2$.

**My attempt:** Suppose that $g \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Hence, for any number $\lambda$, we have
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}\exp\left(\dfrac{g^2}{\lambda^2}\right) & = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left(\dfrac{x^2}{\lambda^2}\right)\exp\left(\dfrac{-x^2}{2}\right)dx\\
    & = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left(\dfrac{-x^2}{2\dfrac{\lambda^2}{\lambda^2-2}}\right)dx\\
\end{align*}
Hence, if $\lambda>\sqrt{2}$ then
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}\exp\left(\dfrac{g^2}{\lambda^2}\right) & = \sqrt{\dfrac{\lambda^2}{\lambda^2-2}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{\dfrac{\lambda^2}{\lambda^2-2}}} \exp\left(\dfrac{-x^2}{2\dfrac{\lambda^2}{\lambda^2-2}}\right)dx\\
    & = \sqrt{\dfrac{\lambda^2}{\lambda^2-2}}.
\end{align*}
So, for $\lambda = 2$, we have
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}\exp\left(\dfrac{g^2}{\lambda^2}\right) = \sqrt{2} < e.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $g$ is $\psi_2$

I wonder whether my proof is correct. The only thing that I wonder about the most is the existence of constant $\lambda$ independent of everything.

Comment: Hi! Is there a reason you've made your integrand so enormous?

Comment: @BrianTung Sorry, I guess this is the difference between my program and Mathstack. I have fixed the issue.

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: @Eric Thank you!