# Prove that $\mathbb{P}\left(\Vert A \Vert \ge cK(\sqrt{N} + \sqrt{K} + t)\right) \le 2\exp(-t^2)$

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, inequality, metric-spaces, inner-products

**Problem:**  Let $A = (a_{ij}): l_2^k \to l_2^N$ be a random matrix whose coefficients $a_{ij}$ are independent, centered, $\psi_2$ [(the definition is in this post)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4861805/getting-familiar-with-the-definition-of-psi-2-random-variable-through-an-exam) and satisfy.
\begin{align*}
        \exists K>0, \forall i,j: \Vert a_{ij}\Vert_{\psi_2} \le K.
\end{align*}

Prove that $\exists c >0$ (independent of everything) such that $\forall t>0$
\begin{align*}
   \mathbb{P}\left(\Vert A \Vert \ge cK(\sqrt{N} + \sqrt{K} + t)\right) \le 2\exp(-t^2).
\end{align*}

**My attempt:** There is two closely related inequality that I have proved but I have not thought how to combine it to tackle with the problem

1. $\forall x \in S^{k-1}$, $\forall y \in S^{N-1}$, $\forall t >0$
   \begin{align*}
           \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}x_jy_i > t\right) \le \exp\left(-\dfrac{t^2}{4K^2}\right).
       \end{align*}
2. Let $\mathcal{N}$ be an $\varepsilon$-net of $S^{k-1}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ be an $\varepsilon$-net of $S^{N-1}$
   \begin{align*}
           \sup_{x \in \mathcal{N},\ y \in \mathcal{M}} \langle Ax,y\rangle  \le \Vert A \Vert \le \dfrac{1}{1-2\varepsilon} \sup_{x \in \mathcal{N}, y \in \mathcal{M}} \langle Ax,y \rangle. \tag{*}
       \end{align*}

I wonder is there any relation between $\mathbb{P}(\Vert A\Vert>\text{constant})$ with $\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}x_jy_i > \text{constant}\right)$

Comment: I think this is the Hanson Wright inequality. This might be a useful resource: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.2872.pdf

Comment: @sudeep5221 Yeah, it looks like very similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before starting the proof for this question, I would like to provide some following results which were proved [here](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf) that we will use then in the main proof.

**Corollary** (Covering numbers of the Euclidean ball).*The covering numbers of the unit Euclidean ball $B_2^n$ satisfy the following for any $\varepsilon>0$ :
$$
\left(\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\right)^n \leq \mathcal{N}\left(B_2^n, \varepsilon\right) \leq\left(\frac{2}{\varepsilon}+1\right)^n .
$$
The same upper bound is true for the unit Euclidean sphere $S^{n-1}$.*

Now, let us go back to the main proof.

**Step 1: Approximation.** Choose $\varepsilon=1 / 4$. Using corollary 1, we can find an $\varepsilon$-net $\mathcal{N}$ of the sphere $S^{k-1}$ and $\varepsilon$-net $\mathcal{M}$ of the sphere $S^{N-1}$ with cardinalities
\begin{align*}
    |\mathcal{N}| \leq 9^k \quad \text { and } \quad|\mathcal{M}| \leq 9^N . \tag{5.1}
\end{align*}

By the inequality was proved in my attempt in the question, the operator norm of $A$ can be bounded using these nets as follows:
\begin{align*}
\|A\| \leq \dfrac{1}{1-2\times\dfrac{1}{4}}\max _{x \in \mathcal{N}, y \in \mathcal{M}}\langle A x, y\rangle =  2 \max _{x \in \mathcal{N}, y \in \mathcal{M}}\langle A x, y\rangle. \tag{5.2}
\end{align*}
**Step 2: Concentration.** Fix $x \in \mathcal{N}$ and $y \in \mathcal{M}$. Then, we have
$$
\langle A x, y\rangle=\sum_{j=1}^k \sum_{i=1}^N a_{i j} x_i y_j
$$

Recalling the result in the result in my attempt (ineq 1.), we can restate this as the tail bound
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\{\langle A x, y\rangle \geq u\} \leq  \exp \left(-u^2 / 4K^2\right), \quad u \geq 0. \tag{5.3}
\end{align*}

**Step 3: Union bound.** Next, we unfix $x$ and $y$ using a union bound. Suppose the event $\max _{x \in \mathcal{N}, y \in \mathcal{M}}\langle A x, y\rangle \geq u$ occurs. Then there exist $x \in \mathcal{N}$ and $y \in \mathcal{M}$ such that $\langle A x, y\rangle \geq u$. Thus the union-bound yields
$$
\mathbb{P}\left\{\max _{x \in \mathcal{N}, y \in \mathcal{M}}\langle A x, y\rangle \geq u\right\} \leq \sum_{x \in \mathcal{N}, y \in \mathcal{M}} \mathbb{P}\{\langle A x, y\rangle \geq u\} .
$$

Using the inequality (5.3) and the estimate (5.1) on the sizes of $\mathcal{N}$ and $\mathcal{M}$, we bound the probability above by
\begin{align*}
9^{k+N} \cdot  \exp \left(- u^2 / 4K^2\right). \tag{5.4}
\end{align*}

If we choose $u=\dfrac{1}{2}C K(\sqrt{N}+\sqrt{k}+t)$, then $u^2 \geq \dfrac{1}{4}C^2 K^2\left(k+N+t^2\right)$, and if the constant $C$ is chosen sufficiently large, the exponent in (5.4) is large enough, say $ u^2 / 4K^2 \geq 3(k+N)+t^2$. Thus
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left\{\max _{x \in \mathcal{N}, y \in \mathcal{M}}\langle A x, y\rangle \geq u\right\} &\leq 9^{k+N} \cdot \exp \left(-3(k+N)-t^2\right)\\
&\leq \exp \left(-t^2\right)\\
& \leq 2\exp\left(-t^2\right).
\end{align*}
Finally, combining this with the inequality (5.2), we can derive that
$$
\mathbb{P}\{\|A\| \geq 2 u\} \leq 2 \exp \left(-t^2\right) .
$$

By the choice of $u$, we finally obtain that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left\{\|A\| \ge  C K(\sqrt{N}+\sqrt{k}+t)\right\} \le 2\exp\left(-t^2\right).
\end{align*}