# Do we have $\mathbb{P}(\Vert A \Vert >\lambda) \le \mathbb{P}(\langle Ax,y\rangle > \lambda)$?

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions

Given that $\Vert A \Vert = \sup\left\{\langle Ax,y \rangle: x,y \in\mathbb{R}^n, \Vert x\Vert_2 = \Vert y\Vert_2 =1\right\}.$ I wonder whether following statements holds:
$$\forall \lambda>0: \mathbb{P}(\Vert A \Vert >\lambda) \le \mathbb{P}(\langle Ax,y\rangle > \lambda).$$

Comment: What's being chosen at random here?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Sorry for the misunderstanding. $A$ in this problem is a matrix with entries that are random variables.

Comment: And $x$ and $y$ are fixed? Are you asking if the statement holds for all $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @MishaLavrov I am asking for all $x,y$. Thank you a lot and sorry if I am too naive.

Comment: This question needs to be clarified. What are $x,y$ on the right hand side above?

Comment: @copper.hat I don't know I understand exactly the problem in the following link. $A$ in the link is a matrix containing random variables and $x,y$ seems to be picked arbitrarily. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4862702/prove-that-mathbbp-left-vert-a-vert-ge-ck-sqrtn-sqrtk-t-right

Answer (score 2):

The inequality should go the other way. (I am assuming that $x,y \in \mathbb R^n$ with $\|x\|_2 = \|y_2\| = 1$, as in the definition of $\|A\|$.)

If $\langle Ax,y\rangle > \lambda$ for some fixed choice of $x$ and $y$, then this implies that $\|A\| > \lambda$: $\|A\|$ is defined to be equal to $\langle Ax,y\rangle$ for the *best* choice of $x$ and $y$ depending on $A$. So the event "$\|A\| > \lambda$" contains the event "$\langle Ax,y\rangle > \lambda$", and therefore we must have $$\Pr[\|A\| > \lambda] \ge \Pr[\langle Ax,y\rangle > \lambda].$$

Comment: I would like to ask this question since I found a very interesting question in the following link. However, I guess it cannot use this approach.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4862702/prove-that-mathbbp-left-vert-a-vert-ge-ck-sqrtn-sqrtk-t-right